# Problem with HTTP Proxy settings and Spring Cloud Kubernetes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am passing the `http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`, `https.proxyHost`, `https.proxyPort`,and `http.nonProxyHosts` properties as Java arguments when I start my Spring Cloud Kubernetes container, but upon container startup I encounter the stack trace below. In addition to the `http.nonProxyHosts` I set, I have also specified the same list (comma-separated and not vertical-bar-separated as in the Java arguments) in the `spring.cloud.kubernetes.client.no-proxy` property.

Is there an additional set of properties that I need to specify within my Spring Cloud Kubernetes microservice that will inform the Kubernetes client code to bypass the HTTP proxy I've set?

To verify that it actually is the HTTP proxy that is causing this issue, when I remove the `http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`, `https.proxyHost`, and `https.proxyPort` properties, the microservice starts successfully.

**Stack Trace**

```
2022-09-14 | 10:06:25.950 | main             | WARN  | .KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource | Trace:
  | Span:                  | Unable to get ConfigMap common-config in namespace common
io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:889)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.listNamespacedConfigMapWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:28375)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.listNamespacedConfigMap(CoreV1Api.java:28263)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.config.KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.getData(KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.java:72)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.config.KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.<init>(KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.java:55)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.config.KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySource(KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:93)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySourceForSingleConfigMap(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:95)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.lambda$locate$0(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:75)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:75)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:51)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:47)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:87)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:607)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.acme.account.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:24)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at io.kubernetes.client.util.credentials.TokenFileAuthentication.intercept(TokenFileAuthentication.java:72)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:885)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
        ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
        ... 64 common frames omitted
2022-09-14 | 10:06:45.854 | main             | WARN  | .KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource | Trace:
  | Span:                  | Unable to get ConfigMap people-edge-config in namespace people
io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:889)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.listNamespacedConfigMapWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:28375)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.listNamespacedConfigMap(CoreV1Api.java:28263)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.config.KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.getData(KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.java:72)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.config.KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.<init>(KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySource.java:55)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.config.KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySource(KubernetesClientConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:93)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySourceForSingleConfigMap(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:95)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.lambda$locate$0(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:75)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:75)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:51)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:47)
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:87)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:607)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.acme.account.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:24)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at io.kubernetes.client.util.credentials.TokenFileAuthentication.intercept(TokenFileAuthentication.java:72)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:885)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
        ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
        ... 64 common frames omitted
2022-09-14 | 10:06:45.881 | main             | INFO  | com.acme.account.Bootstrapper     | Trace:
  | Span:                  | The following 2 profiles are active: "kubernetes", "dev02"
2022-09-14 | 10:06:47.509 | main             | ERROR | o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication | Trace:
  | Span:                  | Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on com.acme.aws.streaming.config.AWSStreamingAutoConfiguration.amazonKinesisAsync
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.acme.account.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:24)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```